# One large scrolling list of different items -> Better solution than RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I was prototyping an app with a recycler view where it boiled down to basically this concept:

There is one single list, which is entirely scrollable (this bit is important).

The items in question in the recycler view are however very heterogeneous. It is not like I want to have either an image or a text, but sometimes it is a simple "list item (clickable text)", sometimes it is a row with 3 buttons, sometimes it is an icon with text, another one is a button, etc.

While similar item types have similar behaviour, the groups itself are different. They need a different manager, a different ViewHolder to process their very different button events etc.

I find it not very convenient to put everything into the recycler view's adapter with some common base class and delegate everything those different items can do to some callbacks. It feels very clunky.

Is there some better way of handling that? The advantage of the recycler view is that it scrolls well. I personally do not need any lazy creation of those items (= recycling) so I am not winning much here. The other advantage is that I do not need to handle every items creation. Which is also the downside, I need to channel it through the adapter with its `getItemViewType` based on position etc.

Comment: what makes you think RecyclerView its not convinient, it sound exactly what you need

Comment: @MarcoPierucci the wiring in the Adapter based on some type and position is the thing I dislike. If the result of this question will be that RecyclerView is the best tool for the job then I will build upon it. I just want to be sure I understand its purpose correctly.

Comment: Use different ViewHolders for different layout in RecyclerView Adapter

Comment: You can use different view holder and even delegate view holder creation and binding thus creating a cleaner architecture by pattern. I do have an implementation of that in a GitHub repository so if you want more info just let me know